# A book about a drug that induces a 24-hour high before death

Tags: story-identification

I am looking for the name of a dystopian book I read 4-5 years ago. The book is about a drug that induces an amazing high for 24 hours before it kills you.

#### Parts of the book I remember

The book starts with a singer who takes the drug, goes onto stage and performs, but dies during his performance. The audience had thought that it was a prank, but turns out it was not.

I remember that the main character's brother is a manufacturer of the drug as well.

I also remember the main character took a fake drug, to fool others. There was a girl with the main character who is trying to stop the drugs. They were trapped in a shipping container because they got found out.

There were also people setting themselves on fire and jumping off roofs because they were radicals. The main character's brother was one of the radicals.

#### Book Cover

The book cover has a green and white pill and I think that there is a skull logo on the pill.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Somehow after asking someone who reads more books than I do to Google it, they found it. The name of the book is "[The Hit](https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/melvin-burgess/the-hit-burgess/)" by Melvin Burgess:

[image: The Hit book cover]

> After 20 years of economic recession, the gaps between England’s rich and poor are wider and starker than ever.
>
> Young lovers Lizzie and Adam are keenly aware of the challenges they face: She’s been raised in a bubble of privilege, while he’s from a family barely scraping by due to his father’s disability. Against this backdrop of economic and social inequity, the hot new recreational drug is Death, which gives its users one extraordinary last week of life, followed by, well, death. Adam and Lizzie are curious, but they steer clear of Death until Adam’s brother, Jess, who’s been keeping their family afloat financially as a chemist, is suddenly revealed to be a member of the revolutionary political group the Zealots (akin to the hacker group Anonymous, if they resorted to self-immolation and suicide bombings). Shattered by the news of his brother’s secret life and presumed death, Adam attends a disastrous party with Lizzie, steals a stash of Death and in a reckless moment of grief, takes the drug. From there, the plot—jam-packed with ill-advised escapades, secret identities, fights and chases—threatens to spiral out of control, but in spite of some Grand Guignol violence administered by grotesque villains just this side of Carl Hiaasen, Burgess’ surprisingly gritty hero and heroine are able to enjoy some muted hopefulness for their pains.

Comment: Congrats! Glad you found your book.

Comment: Thanks! It's been a long time coming